# Laravel Feature Testing match the dynamic value

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I am asserting the `JSON response` in Laravel Feature Testing.

**Response**

```
{
    "message": "OTP verified successfully",
    "phone": "+12312322334",
    "route": "dashboard",
    "_token": "Some Random Value of Token",
    "id": 9
}
```

Here `_token` is dynamically and i do not know the exact outcome. So how to tackle the random string of `_token` field?

```
$response->assertStatus(200)->assertJson([
    "message" => "OTP verified successfully",
    "phone" => "+12312322334",
    "route" => "dashboard",
    "_token" => "how to handle here the random dynamic value",
    "id" => 9,
]);
```

Comment: When you can't know what you are going to get from the other side, at least you can check the type, and if it is a UUID, or similar (where it follows a format) you can check that. Assert as much as possible about that field until you reach the unknown part

Answer (score 0):

As `_token` here is a random `string` and unknown random value. So the case is here we need to check that value is `string` data type.

```
$response->assertStatus(200)
            ->assertJson(
                fn (AssertableJson $json) =>
                $json->where('message', "OTP verified successfully")
                    ->where('phone', "9953029043")
                    ->where('route', "dashboard")
                    ->whereType('_token', 'string')
                    ->where('id', 9)
            );
```